# how to make Django play well with Angular URL

Tags: django, angular

In Angular 2 app that's served by Django, how to make the Angular 2 URL work with Django when reloading the page?

Specifically, say a page served by Django has the url `http://localhost:8000/home`. The page contains 3 tabs and under one of which is an Angular app. Clicking on that tab shows the Angular app, and the url changes to `http://localhost:8000/home/ng_app`. Now if the browser is refreshed with *this url*， Django will show a 404, which makes sense because `http://localhost:8000/home/ng_app` is not present in the Django app.

So how to make the Angular URL work? (entering `http://localhost:8000/home/ng_app` leads to the Angular app instead of 404). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your entire app is served from `/home`, you can just use the following url pattern:

```
urlpattern('/home/.*$', views.my_angular_homepage)
```

If you want to also redirect to the route of everything after you can use any of the standard tricks to capture the trailing part of the URL, and then do a `$location.path` in you angularJS app.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using **hash bangs** in your angular app as URLs. Checkout [this tutorial](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/urls-routing-and-partials/client-side-routing-with-hashbang-urls.html) I found by googling which also uses has bangs for URLs.

In this way the angular app URLs wont conflict with your Django app and Angular would pick it up for routing purposes

Answer (score 0):

Use `url(r'^/home/(?!ng_root/).*$'` where ng_root is the root url of the angular static files.

Checkout my blog post for more details https://4sw.in/blog/2016/django-angular2-tutorial/ .