# ngnix - django 2 -angular 6 / angular routing get 404 after reload page

Tags: django, angular, nginx, django-rest-framework, django-staticfiles

its django and angular 6(use static file) project . i get 404 not found error when i refresh browser ..  i had few search and according this [answer](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831436/how-to-make-django-play-well-with-angular-url) i did same thing this time angular route in refresh work (dont get 404) but i get server error that say following error *please see my uploaded image :

*angular static files are in static folder

```
 "Http failure during parsing for http://robinlearn.com/api/v1/store/view-global-discount/"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
```

[image: full error]

url.py:

```
   urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^(?!ng/).*$', HomePageView.as_view(),name="angular_app")

    ]
    urlpatterns += static(base.STATIC_URL, document_root=base.STATIC_ROOT) + \
               static(base.MEDIA_URL, document_root=base.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(base.ANGULAR_URL, document_root=base.STATIC_ROOT)
```

view:

```
 class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'index.html', context=None)
```

nginx config:

```
    listen 80;
    server_name robinlearn.com;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/bio/academy;
    }

    location / {

        include proxy_params;
       #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/bio/academy/academy.sock;
    }
}
```

setting:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname((__file__)))
#STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR+'/academy/staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join((BASE_DIR),"static")
#MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"media")

SS_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

this is my index.html(in template folder) that load static angular

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" id="persain">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>robin</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'favicon.png' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.9be16346d4b858749d38.css' %}"></head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading .  .  .</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'runtime.6afe30102d8fe7337431.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'polyfills.b0205464c9bd4e7fe3b3.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'scripts.59ed76cc23ba77b0ec72.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main.bfc87555f7931caf0a5b.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your backend API endpoints are not working. Django is returning the index html page instead. Fix your routes

Comment: you need to have your base root '/' to serve the index html page and '/api/....' to serve the backend logic

Comment: how ? can you please write your solution as answer ?

Comment: Is this your code or not? you can start by moving the line url(r'^(?!ng/).*$', HomePageView.as_view(),name="angular_app") to the very bottom isntead of top level like you have now, so that Django would give the priority to API urls assuming one of those lines is your API

Comment: yes you right its fixed now

Comment: Good job! I'll post my comment as an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the line url(r'^(?!ng/).*$', HomePageView.as_view(),name="angular_app") to the very bottom instead of top level like you have right now, so that Django would give the priority to API urls assuming one of those lines is your API